# Kotlin: Any performance impact on converting a "normal" function to a blocking suspend function?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, async-await, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that looks like this:

```
fun <R> map(block: (T) -> R): Result<R> { ... }
```

and I'd like to make a suspending version:

```
suspend fun <R> mapAsync(block: suspend (T) -> R): Result<R> { ... }
```

The logic in both bodies are identical, but one suspends and one doesn't.

I don't want to have this duplicated logic. The only way I found for this to work is to have the `map` function call to the `mapAsync` function and then wrap the result in `runBlocking`:

```
fun <R> map(block: (T) -> R): Result<R> =
    runBlocking { mapAsync { block(it) } }
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is there any performance considerations in taking a "normal" function, passing it as a `suspend` parameter, then block until the result is done?

   - Based on what I've read, it sounds like the initial thread keeps "doing the work" inside the suspend block until it hits the first suspend point. Then, the continuation is put into the wait queue and the initial thread is free to perform other work.
   - However, in this case, there isn't any "real" suspend point because the actual function is just `(T) -> R`, though I don't know if the compiler can tell that.
   - I'm worried that this setup is actually utilizing another thread from the pool that is just notifying my first thread to wake up...
2. Is there a better way to have a suspend and non-suspend set of functions utilize the same code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have encountered the infamous "[colored function](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/)" problem. The two worlds are indeed separate and, while you can add a superficial layer that unifies them, you can't get it at zero performance cost. This is so fundamental that, even assuming that your `suspend` block never actually suspends, and the wrapping layer leverages that assumption and doesn't even use `runBlocking` on it, you will *still* pay the price of "being ready to suspend". The price isn't huge, though: it means creating a small object per each `suspend fun` call that holds the data that would normally reside on the thread's native call stack. In your case only the outer block is suspendable, so that's just one such object.

`runBlocking` runs the coroutine on the thread where you called it and it will finish synchronously on the same thread unless it suspends itself. Therefore your case where you'd have some synchronous code in a `suspend` block wouldn't suffer an additional performance hit from thread coordination.

If the coroutine does suspend itself, then there will have to be some external worker thread which will react to the event that allows the coroutine to resume, and there will have to be some coordination between that thread and your original `runBlocking` thread. This is a fundamental mechanism that's there with or without coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, `runBlocking` was specifically designed to serve as a connection between blocking and non-blocking operations. From the documentation:

> Runs new coroutine and blocks current thread interruptibly until its
>   completion. This function should not be used from coroutine. **It is
>   designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written
>   in suspending style**, to be used in main functions and in tests.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

Also further read:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/basics.md#bridging-blocking-and-non-blocking-worlds

And some interesting videos by Roman Elizarov:

https://youtu.be/_hfBv0a09Jc

https://youtu.be/a3agLJQ6vt8